# UI Router dynamic URL matcher

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UI-router, is there a way that I only allow dynamic urls to be allowed.

For example, I have a service, `MyData` that has a `get` method which uses `$http`. It returns a list of entries. What I would like to do is construct an array of valid entry ids which the $state url can use to only allow those.

```
var validArray = MyData.get().then(function(res) {
   var arr = _.chain(res).pluck('id').flatten().value();
   console.log(arr);
   // returns [12, 15, 20, 26];
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is ONLY allowing those array items to be accessed via the `$state` url.

```
$stateProvider
   .state('entry', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/entry/{id:int}', // is there a way to only allow those values from validArray?
      resolve: { //etc }
   })
   .state('entry.detail', {
      url: '/detail',
      // etc...
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2wqKkhZtiX8XgZeVZdZO?p=info)

I would, in this case, use an event - to check if the id is valid. That would allow us to not only use `$http` *(**`.run()`** phase)*, but we can more precisly decide what to do if id is wrong. So let's have these links:

```
  <a ui-sref="entry({id:1})">
  <a ui-sref="entry({id:22})">
  <a ui-sref="entry({id:333})">
  <a ui-sref="entry({id:4444})">
```

And this could be our data.json with supported ids:

```
{
  "allowedIds": [
    22, 333
  ]
}
```

With this service we can check if the id is allowed. It also returns promise in case, that $http was not used to load the data from server:

```
.factory('IdValidator', ['$http',
  function($http) {

    var allowedIds = null;

    // return bool or promise
    var  validate = function(id){

      if(allowedIds){
        return isValid(id);
      }

      return $http
        .get("data.json")
        .then(function(resp){
          allowedIds = resp.data.allowedIds;
          return isValid(id);
        })
    }
    // compare id with loaded allowed ids
    var isValid = function(id){
      return allowedIds.indexOf(id) >= 0;
    }

    return {
      validate : validate
    }

}]);
```

And finally, we need to do some decision on state change:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'IdValidator',
  function($rootScope, $state, IdValidator) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, to, params) {

      if (to.name !== "entry"){
        return;
      }

      var result = IdValidator.validate(params.id) ;

      // allowedIds loaded, we now that this id is OK
      if(result === true){
         return;
      }

      // now we have to stop exectuion any how
       event.preventDefault();  

      // result is false - id is not allowed
      if(result === false){

         $state.go("home");
         return;
      }

      // wait for a promise and try this state again
      result.then(function(isValid){

        $state.go(to.name, params);

      })

    });
}])
```

It should be clear. If result is `true` or `false`, we can act.. if result is promise, we just wait for its resolve.. and then redirect to this state again

This way, we have under our control allowed ids through the whole app life cycle...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2wqKkhZtiX8XgZeVZdZO?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, but something very similar to what you require can be found in the ui-router api docs for [$urlMatcherFactory](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$urlMatcherFactory).

It essentially allows you to create a custom route parameter constraint so your `url` entry could look like:

```
url: '/entry/{id:validIds}
```

And then define a custom url matcher

```
var list = [12, 15, 20, 26];

$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('validIds', {
  encode: function(item) {
    // Represent the list item in the URL using its corresponding index
    return list.indexOf(item);
  },
  decode: function(item) {
    // Look up the list item by index
    return list[parseInt(item, 10)];
  },
  is: function(item) {
    // Ensure the item is valid by checking to see that it appears
    // in the list
    return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
  }
});
```

That would need to be in a `angular.config` section, so from there you'd have to work through how to get the valid ids in.

(Note, the code above was amended from the linked documentation, so may not work 100%)

Comment: How do you handle invalid id with your example and redirect to another state like 404 or search?